# Преобразование HEX->DEC без изменения системы счисления

Tags: c#

есть данные в hex файле примерно такого вида:
byte[] data = {0x11 0x48 0x42 0x50 0x00 0x00}
здесь записано значение 1148.42500000 в dec. Не знаю что за сумрачный гений такое придумал...
два первых байта всегда целая часть, 4 следующих байта  - дробная.
Нужно как-то вытаскивать float из этого массива байт.
Придумал такое решение:

```
float.Parse(bytes[0].ToString("X2") + bytes[1].ToString("X2") + "." + bytes[2].ToString("X2") + bytes[3].ToString("X2"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

существует ли более элегантное решение для этого?

Comment: первые два числа в исходной строке - всегда числа до точки?

Comment: @timur да, два первых байта - целая часть, 4 следующих байта - дробная.

Comment: Это упакованные двоично-десятичные числа с фиксированной точкой, и преобразовывать их во `float` может быть не лучшей идеей, если не хотите, чтобы `9999.9999` превратилось в `10000.0`, а `0.3` в `0.300000011920928955078125`. Возможно сумрачный гений хотел избежать именно этого.

Comment: @extrn Для меня это новый тип данных. Почитал статью здесь https://ru.qwe.wiki/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal. Спасибо, теперь хоть знаю что это не идея сумрачного гения, а стандарт))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует менее затратное решение для конвертирования во float :

```
        byte[] data = { 0x11, 0x48, 0x42, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00 };

        float result = 0;

        foreach (byte bt in data)
        {
            result *= 100;                
            result += (float)(10*(bt >> 4) + (bt & 0xf));   
        }
        result /= 100000000;

        Console.WriteLine(result); //1148.425
```

Comment: Тот случай, когда вариант без цикла ненамного больше чем вариант с циклом) А на ассемблере вообще одна команда - `aad 16` кажется.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
byte[] bytes = { 0x11, 0x48, 0x42, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00 };

float result = float.Parse(
    string.Join("", bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))).Insert(4, ","));

Console.WriteLine(result);  //=> 1148,425
```

Comment: я наверно не верно сформулировал исходные данные. Они byte[]

Comment: @Deim ок, исправил

Comment: Вставляется запятая, но культура не указывается. `float.Parse` выкинет исключение на системах, где по умолчанию используется культура с точкой в качестве разделителя. Не надо так делать.

Answer (score 0):

Старшая часть легко отделяется от младшей. Наверно разработчик очень любил двочно-десятичное кодирование. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4  Старшая часть от младшей можно отделить сдвигом на 4 или делением на 16, а младшую - остаток от деления на 16 либо "and 15".

Я бы расшифровал бы так (для любителей линейного выражения):

```
byte[] d = {0x11, 0x48, 0x42 ,0x50, 0x00, 0x00};
double result =  
(d[0]>>4)*1000 +   (d[0]&15)*100 + 
(d[1]>>4)*10 +     (d[1]&15)*1 + 
(d[2]>>4)*.1 +     (d[2]&15)*.01+ 
(d[3]>>4)*.001 +   (d[3]&15)*.0001+
(d[4]>>4)*.00001 + (d[4]&15)*.000001;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Если громоздко - можно обвернуть в цикл (для любителей циклов).

```
byte[] d = {0x11, 0x48, 0x42 ,0x50, 0x00, 0x00};
double multi = 100;
double result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++ ) {
   result += (d[i]>>4)*10*multi + (d[i]&15)*multi;
   multi =multi/100.0;
   }
```